# How do I get the Kubuntu upgrade notification icon back?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, notification

When Kubuntu needs to be upgraded between versions (e.g. 9.10 to 10.04), there's a notifier icon that shows up in the system tray,

[image: upgrade icon]

([Source](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-kubuntu-9.10-karmic-koala-to-10.04-lucid-lynx))

But if I click on it to start the upgrade and it fails for some reason (in my case, not enough space on the `/boot` partition), the icon disappears. How can I either get it back, or run the upgrade manually, without having to log out and log back in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up KPackageKit in Kickoff (under the Computer tab), and it should offer to install updates.

If KPK can't do it:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Hm, I thought I did that and it only gave me 4 updates, the regular security/bugfix complement... but I'll go back and try it again to check.

Answer (score 0):

The program that places the icon in the tray is a python script, `update-notifier-kde`, and it can be run from the terminal as

```
python /usr/bin/update-notifier-kde
```

(`sudo` not required, it will prompt for the password graphically)